# Calling a method from another method in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make some modifications to a Node.js app that I forked, what I am trying to do is call a function within another one.

I have attempted a crack at this by simply calling the method as follows but I'm not really that familiar with Node.js so I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

```
'use strict';


/*
 * initalize the class
 */
function MessageBot(bot, user, cache) {
  this.bot      = bot;
  this.user     = user;
  this.cache    = cache;
}

/*
 * perform commands
 */
MessageBot.prototype.librarySearch = function(searchText) {
     var self = this;
     // call SOS function - this is the bit that doesn't work
     MessageBot.prototype.callSos(somenumbervar);
}

MessageBot.prototype.callSos = function(number) {
     // do something else here
     var self = this;
     var commandList = self.cache.get('commandList');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `this` ostensibly inherits the prototype (directly or indirectly).  Therefore, you can just do `this.callSos(somenumbervar)`.

If you want to reach the method through the prototype, you have to tell it what `this` is.  With your current code, `this` in `callSos()` will be `MessageBot.prototype` -- certainly not what you want.  So you can also do `MessageBot.prototype.callSos.call(this, somenumbervar)`.

Which approach to take depends on how dynamic you want your objects to be.  For example, if you want consumers of `MessageBot` to be able to "override" `callSos()` by installing their own method, then you should take the first approach (`this.callSos()`) as it will look up `callSos` in the object's inheritance chain.  This process will only reach the method you've installed on the prototype if the method hasn't been overridden.  IMO this is the approach you should take unless you have a very good reason not to.

See this example, which demonstrates how the two approaches differ regarding overriding, while also showing that both work with regards to passing the correct `this` value (since both methods can retrieve the expected value from `this.data`):

```js
function ClassA(data) {
  this.data = data;
}

ClassA.prototype.foo = function () {
  console.log("this.bar() returned: " + this.bar());
  console.log("ClassA.prototype.bar.call(this) returned: " + ClassA.prototype.bar.call(this));
};

ClassA.prototype.bar = function () {
  return 'in the ClassA prototype, our data is ' + this.data;
};

console.log('--obj1-- (no override)');
var obj1 = new ClassA(3.14);
obj1.foo();

console.log('--obj2-- (override)');
var obj2 = new ClassA(42);
obj2.bar = function () {
  return 'in an overriding method, our data is ' + this.data;
};

obj2.foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer along with examples, I receive errors relating to my cache variable `Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`. Could you explain how to correctly access this?

Comment: @Imran Right, that's because `this` is `MessageBot.prototype` in your example, which doesn't have a `cache` attribute. You need to incorporate one of the approaches in my answer to solve the problem.